# Regarding differences between how MSVC and g++ treat C++ template code

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I stumbled across this piece of code from ACCU (http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1916) and is interested in applying AOP in C++ by using CRTP for a fun project. The code given by the author is as follows:

```
namespace aop
{

template <class A>
class NullAspect
{};

template <template <template <class> class> class Base>
struct Decorate
{
private:
    struct None {};

    template <template <class> class ... Aspects>
    struct Apply;

    template <template <class> class T>
    struct Apply<T>
    {
        template <class E>
        using Type = T<E>;
    };

    template<template < class > class A1, template < class > class ... Aspects>
    struct Apply<A1, Aspects...>
    {
        template <class T>
        using Type = A1<typename Apply<Aspects...>::template Type<T>>; // the errors point to this line and the 'Type' refers to the 'template Type<T>'
    };

public:
    template<template <class> class ... Aspects>
    struct with
    {
        template <class T>
        using AspectsCombination = typename Apply<Aspects...>::template Type<T>;

        typedef AspectsCombination<Base<AspectsCombination>> Type;
    };
};
}
```

I tried compiling it in Microsoft VS2015 and it gave me the following set of errors:

```
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'Type'  
Error   C2947   expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '<'    
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'T'    
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   
Error   C1201   unable to continue after syntax error in class template definition  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '}'    
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

I took the same code, checked the syntax and compiled it in g++ and it compiled fine. Are there any discrepancy between the 2 compilers that I should be aware of? What is the issue here that makes cl.exe generate these errors? Are they due to the fact that how cl.exe parse any template based code? What changes are needed to get this code to work on msvc?

Edit:

Here's the complete code for test.cpp as provided by the author to help you guys get a clearer picture:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "aop.h"

//#define INHERITING_CTORS  as of g++ 6.4.3, inheriting ctors was not implemented

template <typename _UnderlyingType>
struct Number
{
    template <template <class> class A = aop::NullAspect>
    class Type
    {
    public:
        typedef _UnderlyingType UnderlyingType;
        typedef A<Number::Type<A>> FullType;

        Type(UnderlyingType n)
            : n(n)
        {}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Type& number)
        {
            return out << number.n;
        }
    protected:
        UnderlyingType n;
    };
};

template <class A>
class ArithmeticAspect: public A
{
public:
    typedef typename A::FullType FullType;

#ifdef INHERITING_CTORS
    using A::A;
#else
    ArithmeticAspect(typename A::UnderlyingType n)
        : A(n)
    {}

    ArithmeticAspect(const A& a)
        : A(a)
    {}
#endif

    FullType operator+(const FullType& other) const
    {
        FullType tmp(*this);
        return tmp += other;
    }

    FullType operator-(const FullType& other) const
    {
        FullType tmp(*this);
        return tmp -= other;
    }

    FullType operator+=(const FullType& other)
    {
        A::n += other.n;
        return A::n;
    }

    FullType operator-=(const FullType& other)
    {
        A::n -= other.n;
        return A::n;
    }

    // same for *, *=, /, /=
};

template <class A>
class IncrementalAspect: public A
{
public:
    typedef typename A::FullType FullType;

#ifdef INHERITING_CTORS
    using A::A;
#else
    IncrementalAspect(typename A::UnderlyingType n)
        : A(n)
    {}

    IncrementalAspect(const A& a)
        : A(a)
    {}
#endif

    FullType operator++(int)
    {
        FullType tmp(*this);
        operator++();
        return tmp;
    }

    FullType operator++()
    {
        ++A::n;
        return *this;
    }

    FullType operator--(int)
    {
        FullType tmp(*this);
        operator--();
        return tmp;
    }

    FullType operator--()
    {
        --A::n;
        return *this;
    }
};

/*
* Configurable Aspect sumExample
*/
template <unsigned int PRECISION>
struct RoundAspect
{
    template <class A>
    class Type : public A
    {
    public:
        typedef typename A::FullType FullType;

#ifdef INHERITING_CTORS
        using A::A;
#else
        Type(typename A::UnderlyingType n)
            : A(n)
        {}

        Type(const A& a)
            : A(a)
        {}
#endif

        FullType operator+(const FullType& other) const
        {
            return FullType(round(A::operator+(other).n));
        }

    private:
        static float round(float f)
        {
            const unsigned int e = std::pow(10, PRECISION);
            return float(int(f * e)) / e;
        }
    };
};

template <class A>
class LogicalAspect: public A
{
public:
    typedef typename A::FullType FullType;

#ifdef INHERITING_CTORS
    using A::A;
#else
    LogicalAspect(typename A::UnderlyingType n)
        : A(n)
    {}

    LogicalAspect(const A& a)
        : A(a)
    {}
#endif

    bool operator!() const
    {
        return !A::n;
    }

    bool operator&&(const FullType& other) const
    {
        return A::n && other.n;
    }

    bool operator||(const FullType& other) const
    {
        return A::n || other.n;
    }
};

template <class A>
class BitwiseAspect: public A
{
public:
    typedef typename A::FullType FullType;

#ifdef INHERITING_CTORS
    using A::A;
#else
    BitwiseAspect(typename A::UnderlyingType n)
        : A(n)
    {}

    BitwiseAspect(const A& a)
        : A(a)
    {}
#endif

    bool operator~() const
    {
        return ~A::n;
    }

    FullType operator&(const FullType& mask) const
    {
        return A::n & mask.n;
    }

    FullType operator|(const FullType& mask) const
    {
        return A::n | mask.n;
    }

    FullType operator<<(const FullType& bitcount) const
    {
        return A::n << bitcount.n;
    }

    FullType operator>>(const FullType& bitcount) const
    {
        return A::n >> bitcount.n;
    }

    FullType& operator>>=(const FullType& bitcount)
    {
        A::n >>= bitcount.n;
        return *static_cast<FullType*>(this);
    }
};

template <class N>
void sumExample(typename N::UnderlyingType n1, typename N::UnderlyingType n2)
{
    N a(n1);
    N b(n2);
    N c = a + b;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

template <class N>
void orExample(typename N::UnderlyingType n1, typename N::UnderlyingType n2)
{
    N a(n1);
    N b(n2);
    std::cout << (a || b) << std::endl;
}

template <class N>
void bitwiseExample(typename N::UnderlyingType n1, typename N::UnderlyingType n2)
{
    N a(n1);
    N b(n2);
    std::cout << (a + ((b >>= 1) << 3)) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    typedef aop::Decorate<Number<unsigned int>::Type>::with<ArithmeticAspect, IncrementalAspect, LogicalAspect, BitwiseAspect>::Type IntegralNumber;
    bitwiseExample<IntegralNumber>(1, 2);
    sumExample<IntegralNumber>(1, 2);

    typedef aop::Decorate<Number<float>::Type>::with<RoundAspect<2>::Type, ArithmeticAspect, LogicalAspect>::Type FloatRoundLogicalNumber;
    orExample<FloatRoundLogicalNumber>(1, 0);

    typedef aop::Decorate<Number<int>::Type>::with<LogicalAspect>::Type IntLogicalNumber;
    orExample<IntLogicalNumber>(1, 0);

    typedef aop::Decorate<Number<float>::Type>::with<RoundAspect<2>::Type, ArithmeticAspect>::Type FloatRoundNumber;
    sumExample<FloatRoundNumber>(1.339, 1.1233);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `AspectOrientedProgramming` does not show up in your example code, which code did you actualy compile? which VS version are you using?

Comment: Sorry AspectOrientedProgramming is the name of the solution for the project. Let me clean it further. Also the version is VS2015.

Comment: at which line numbers do these errors occur?

Comment: I added a comment in the code block that is where the error occurred.  "using Type = A1<typename Apply<Aspects...>::template Type<T>>; " this one to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO it is the  `>>` syndrom on templated templates. Before C++11, a space was required to have to separate `>` token and not one `>>` token.

Starting from C++ 11 n4296 draft says in 14.2 Names of template specializations [temp.names] §3:

> ... Similarly, the first non-nested >> is treated as two consecutive but
>   distinct > tokens, the first of which is taken as the end of the template-argument-list and completes the
>   template-id.

It looks like MSVC2015 has not still implemented that part of standard (or you may have forgotten to declare the C++ version of the source*)

For sake of completeness, when compiling with CLang 3.4.1 without specifying `std=c++11` it show this error:

> ```
> error: a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
>     using Type = A1<typename Apply<Aspects...>::template Type<T>>; // the er...
> ```

and hopefully not even a warning in C++11 mode...

(*) unfortunately, I have no access to a VS2015, by Microsoft declares int their [C++11/14/17 Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx) page that [Right angle brackets](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1757.html) is implemented by VS2013 and 2015. So I assume there should be somewhere in the project properties a *code level* indication.

Comment: That's what I did too but the same set of errors are still generated. I am currently flipping books and reading around the web on C++ templates, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the line.

Comment: @XavierRXTan: MSVC claims that it is already implemented. My advice would be to thoroughly review project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

So after fiddling around and reading whatever I can, I finally sent the original author an email. So all credit goes to him, Mr. Hugo Arregui.

With respect to the line that cl is complaining, the fix is the following:

```
template < template <class> class A1, template <class> class A2, template <class> class... Aspects>
struct Apply<A1,A2,Aspects...>
{
    template<class T>
    using Type = A1< typename Apply<A2, Aspects...>::template Type<T> >;
};
```

It would be great if anyone knows why Microsoft's compiler requires us to expand at least 2 template class in the template argument and give an explanation here. Was talking to the author this and he was surprised as well.